# How to apply a formula to all rows in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I write a formula (=IF(B1>3, 1,0) for a cell in my new column. How could apply the same formula to the other rows? for example for row3 (=IF(B3>3,1,0) for row4 (=IF(B4>3,1,0) and etc.

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom right corner of a cell or cell selection, you should see a little square/dot. Clicking and dragging that down will copy that formula to the rows you drag it over. If you enter your formula in two rows and then select both rows before dragging the square/dot down, it will apply it based on the pattern it finds (B3 and B4 will make it change it to B5, B6). Drag to the bottom of the spreadsheet to apply to all rows.

Comment: You shouldn't need to enter the formula in more than one cell before you can drag down to fill the other rows. You can also double click the little dot and it will fill all the way down until there is a gap in an adjacent cell. Especially useful if your spreadsheet goes down further than your monitor will show.  Lastly, you can highlight all the cells you want your formula to go into, type the formula and press control-enter and it will put whatever you typed into all of the highlighted cells.

Comment: That is probably true. I'm just more used to using that feature for filling something such as timestamps where it would only copy what the cell contains verbatim unless there's a pattern.